# How to enable view full location of class (file) in info menu? IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

[image]

IntelliJ IDEA. It is info menu (when you stop cursor on class name). **How to enable view full location of class (file)?** Example: Oleg_Library.main.java.src.mypackage.Test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible afaik. But you can create a feature request for it in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I am already write to developers IDE and they add this feature.